# Possible detection of CVE: 2021-04-23 logged in event viewer (23/04/2021 @15:54:16)

Tags: security, powershell, event-viewer, exploit

A Possible detection of CVE: 2021-04-23 logged in event viewer (23/04/2021 @15:54:16)
I am currently scanning my machine, but will Win Defender be able to remove the infection?

Randomly I've been learning how to query Event Viewer via PowerShell and output as an HTML report. What a coincidence!

[Image from Event Viewer report showing the event viewer message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlw5Z.png)

Edit:
[0 Threats found by Windows Defender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdQlL.png)

I also performed a complete offline scan, no threats found. Added MBAM Premium to this machine, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Full Scan with Windows Defender. You may also want to scan in Safe Mode.  That will ensure it gets picked up.

Once fully scanned, the threat will land in the Quarantine.

Windows Defender is a top rated AV App.

Comment: Thanks John, I ran the scan. It didn't show any threats so I will take it that the attempt was blocked, which is great.  I'll run some checks later today, and as I have MBAM Premium on another machine, I added it here for a bit extra. (trying the double space to add line breaks </br>, may not work)